# How to navigate from preference screen to a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, android-jetpack

I am building an app where there is a settings screen which I build with Andreoid Jetpack Preference library. I want to travel from the preference screen into a more detailed fragment in order to personalize email. But I don know how to handle the click on the preference, I have managed to import the method provided from the library but I dont know how to implement it as there is no information available. I have the function onPreferenceClick but i dont know how to build its logic. It shall return false when it is not clicked and true when it is.

```
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    if (onPreferenceClick(preferenceScreen.getPreference(1))) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment)
    }

    override fun onPreferenceClick(preference: Preference?): Boolean {
    preference?.setOnPreferenceClickListener {

        }
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, here is the code if someone has the same trouble.

```
val showValueListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment)
        true
    }
findPreference<Preference>("email")?.onPreferenceClickListener = showValueListener
```

Comment: Please explain why my answer not right? My answer same your answer with java code.

Comment: cause I asked for a solution using kotlin and android jetpack, not java.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, you can override `onCreatePreferences` to handle click on preference:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.your_preference);

        Preference preferenceMap = findPreference("your_preference_key");

        preferenceMap.setOnPreferenceClickListener(
                new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.editMailFragment)
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }
```